# Add marker to existing google map (without refresh google map)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map on my website (in production) with few markers, i would like to know if its possible to add a marker on an existing map without refresh my google map.

This what i have:

- I load my webpage, google map appears with markers
- On click on a button, i would like to add one marker on my map (without refresh my page or the google map)

I can realize this with refresh my google map but i think that its better to do this without refresh due to limitation of google map display per day.

This is my code:

```
    <button onclick="addMarker()">Add marker</button>
<script>
    function addMarker(){
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(44, 6);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
            });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: your `map`-variable isn't global accessible when it doesn't work. Additionally: you should give the button the `type`-attribute `button`, otherwise it will be a submit-button.

Answer (score 2):

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.745334, 12.738430);

function addmarker(latilongi) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latilongi,
        title: 'new marker',
        draggable: true,
        map: map
    });
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition())
}

$('#btnaddmarker').on('click', function() {
    addmarker(latlng)
})
```

Comment: Would map work properly within addmarker(latilongi) or would you want to pass it via addmarker(latilongi, map) in case you have multiple maps?

Comment: In my case it doesnt work, it refresh my map. My map is styled (black and white colors), when i click on my button, the map appears without my colors (black and white) and it seems that the map was refresh

Comment: Can you please give us a jsfiddle of your map?

Comment: Yes this is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/anna33/z5mojbve/7/ Thank u

Answer (score 0):

Yes. When you added your markers originally, your probably did something like:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
  title: 'Hello World!'
});
```

The map already existed (map: map), and you added markers. You can do the same thing later to add more markers.